# How to check for child's process memory

Tags: c, memory

I would like to check for my child process memory :

What I want to do, is a program that will launch another program, and check for all the variables the child create, and print out their values.

Like what valgrind does, but printing out the variables values.

I would also like to be able to run the passed program step by step.

What I would like to know is how to check a program's values, and how to run step by step.

If know how to do it in C, it would be even better !!!

I could not find any help online that would answer my questions.

Everything I found whas using gdb or other debuggers. I would like to do it without.

Thanks !

Edit : As mentioned by Bodo, Valgrind modify library functions.

If it's needed, why not. Actualy, what I want to do looks like a debugger, with less possibilities.

I only want to be able to *see* variables values, as well as run the program steps by steps.

EDIT :

I would like to have a C program that I could run like that :

```
./my_program ./some_other_compiled_objects
```

That would run `./some_other_compiled_objects` but will stop at each "steps" (assembly instructions ?) and get all the variables and their values (for the display, i don't care, i'll probably do it with curses later on)

Response to the comment asking for more precisions

Comment: A child process runs independent from the parent process. Valgrind modifies your program by replacing library functions. It looks like you want to implement a debugger, which is a fairly big task. Please [edit] your question and explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment:  This is an “I want a pony” type of question that’s difficult to answer concisely and is off-topic on Stack Overflow. If you can, make an attempt and then show us your code we can understand what you’re trying to do on a technical level. Even a small amount of code, however incomplete or broken, can give us context and illustrate your intentions. Instead of leaving us to speculate on what you might need, give us something to build so we can focus help in those areas where it’s most needed.

Comment: Remember, once a program is compiled the very concept of "variable" goes out the window, except if you explicitly build for debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to write a *debugger* (as you expressed in your question).  You have a perfect example with `gdb(1)`, which apart of being a good debugger, *it's open source*, so you can access its source code to see how things are made.  Beware that, after reading below, you will probably get a better way, by indirectly controlling `gdb(1)` yourself, and allowing it to intermediate between the program being debugged and your program (this was done in cgdb(1) to give you a *ncurses* view of what was happening inside gdb, by havin a colored view of the source code simultaneously to gdb run).  Or probably you don't even know the existence of `gdb(1)`.  In that case, a reading to the gdb documentation will suffice to answer your question.

As you will see there, as in unix, for a process is impossible to have access to the memory of another process, you will need special features to become a debugger.  You can attach a piece of code to the debugged process to act as a *memory space server* that allows you to ask for the process variables and the like  (this is done for example in the Java Virtual Machine, or in many microcontrollers, whose memory is not accessible if you don't do a similar feature).  This allows the process to install breakpoints (points in which the binary code is overwritten by a JMP instruction to the entry point of the debugger, so when the program reaches the point of the breakpoint, stops for the debugger to become in control)  there are many ways to solve the same problem, some of them require that you modify the program, some don't.  But the ones that don't give far less control, as the program doesn't give any support to be debugged.

A source code debugger, normally requires also access to the debugging symbols (these are normally written to the executable binary, when you request compilation with debugging support) to allow to interpret the objects in memory as variables, functions or the different kinds of objects you can have in your program, to allow what is called *source code debugging*.  It would take a full book just to enumerate the possibilities here, an the complexity of what you ask for.

I will not extend more on this, you have been requested in the comments to be more specific, but my opinion is that you are not aware of the complexity of what you are asking about, so this explanation will suffice for now.

Comment: Thank you very much !
I actualy never looked enough on gdb (and now cgdb, it's incredible !)
Your answer is realy good !
apreciate that !